# React Native Specify file format for addImageFromBase64 on iOS

Tags: ios, react-native

Is it possible to save an image from a base64, with a file extension in the name?

As per
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Image/RCTImageStoreManager.m#L54
it looks like the `imageTag`, i.e. file name, is constructed form the *path* and a simple incremental *id*. Extension is not considered.

Is there another way to append the extension, preferably with standard APIs?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using RN's ImageStore? Don't know if this is the best way to do it, but the ImageStore will return the uri and you could use react-native-fs to read the base64 from that file and write it to whatever path/extension you would like it to have.

Don't forget to also removeImageForTag(uri) afterwards so you don't have both files.

react-native-fs: https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I'm using Exponent, and they currently don't support third party libraries, with custom native code, so I'm hoping for a standard solution. If it were to be possible to use _react-native-fs_, I guess I could even skip the `addImageFromBase64` part, and directly save the base64 string with the chosen filename.

Comment: I found an exponent-react-native-fs library that's written completely in JS, but it hasn't been updated for a while so it might not work..